# Using Underscore.js to filter an array of objects on a property using a 'contains'

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects which I would like to filter using a contains/any method on a property using underscore.

For example, if I had the following variables:

```
var people = [
{
    name: 'Dave',
    age: 26
},
{
    name: 'Frank',
    age: 23
}];
var allowedAges = [20, 23, 24];
```

I would like to use underscore to end up with a result like:

```
 var allowedPeople = [];
 _.each(_.where(people, { age: _.any()}), function (person) {
            allowedPeople.push(person);
        });
```

And there may also be occasions where *allowedAges* is an array of objects and id want to use the contains/any on the *people* array using a property of the objects in allowedAges.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JS equivalent of `contains` is usually [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in rare cases).

You can use [the built-in `Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do this like:

```
people.filter(function (person) {
  return allowedAges.indexOf(person.age) !== -1; // -1 means not present
});
```

or with underscore, using the same predicate:

```
_.filter(people, function (person) {
  return allowedAges.indexOf(person.age) !== -1; // -1 means not present
}
```

If you have access to ES6 collections or a polyfill for [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), you can replace the `allowedAges` array with a set (enforcing unique values) and simply use [`Set.prototype.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has):

```
people.filter(person => allowedAges.has(person.age))
```

Comment: The OP asked for an underscore solution, not a plain js solution. I can't downvote this because you've answered the question as asked, and the pure js solution can be seen as extra info, but why is the pure js stuff necessary at all given that the OP exlicitly asked a question about underscore? And, why is the 'native' part of your answer first?

Comment: @EngineerDollery "I would like to use underscore" Doesn't mean he must use underscore, no where did they state "This must be done using underscore"

Comment: @EngineerDollery To promote the built in methods. A lot of people forget about them, but in most browsers now, underscore just defers to them ( underscore is largely a polyfill from before arrays had functional methods). Since the OP asked about underscore, the equivalent solution is there just in case.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, here's an underscore solution that works with a mixed array of integers and objects containing an `age` property.

```
var allowedPeople = _.filter(people, (p) =>
  _.some(allowedAges, (a) => (a.age || a) === p.age)
);
```

Comment: Two different times I've searched and found this post, and both times the first two answers yielded empty arrays for me, but this one from Aldehir has worked both times.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use vanilla js [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

```
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Dave',
    age: 26
  },
  {
    name: 'Frank',
    age: 23
  }
];

var allowedAges = [20, 23, 24];

var allowedPeople = people.filter(function((person, i, arr) {
  return allowedAges.indexOf(person.age) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: The OP asked for an underscore solution, not a plain js solution.

Comment: @EngineerDollery it's very possible OP didn't know there was a non-underscore solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure JS version:

```js
var people = [{
  name: 'Dave',
  age: 26
}, {
  name: 'Frank',
  age: 23
}];
var allowedAges = [20, 23, 24];

function filterData(arr, key, searchList){
  var result = [];
  if(Array.isArray(searchList)){
    result = arr.filter(function(item){
      return (searchList.indexOf(item[key])>-1);
    });
  }
  else{
    result = arr.filter(function(item){
      return (searchList === item[key]);
    });
  }
  return result;
}

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(filterData(people,"age", allowedAges), 0, 4) + "</pre>")
```

Comment: The OP asked for an underscore solution, not a plain js solution.